# PyQt5 tray program closes after QDialog executing

Tags: python, pyqt5, qdialog, trayicon

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QCheckBox, QSystemTrayIcon, \
    QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QMenu, QAction, QStyle, qApp, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    check_box = None
    tray_icon = None

    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))
        self.setWindowTitle("System Tray Application")
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        grid_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Application, which can minimize to Tray", self), 0, 0)

        self.check_box = QCheckBox('Minimize to Tray')
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.check_box, 1, 0)
        grid_layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding), 2, 0)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Dialog', self)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 1)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.dial_func)

        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_ComputerIcon))

        show_action = QAction("Show", self)
        quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        hide_action = QAction("Hide", self)
        dial = QAction('Dial', self)
        dial.triggered.connect(self.dial_func)
        show_action.triggered.connect(self.show)
        hide_action.triggered.connect(self.hide)
        quit_action.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        tray_menu = QMenu()
        tray_menu.addAction(show_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(hide_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(dial)
        tray_menu.addAction(quit_action)
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(tray_menu)
        self.tray_icon.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.check_box.isChecked():
            event.ignore()
            self.hide()
            self.tray_icon.showMessage(
                "Tray Program",
                "Application was minimized to Tray",
                QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
                2000
            )

    def dial_func(self):
        text, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input dialog', 'Enter your name')

        if ok:
            print('simple text', text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I am trying to write little application for diagnostic. Application should work in tray and have options to change settings from QDialog.
With this code, I can run dialog from btn (in main window) and from Dial (from QMenu). And if program not in tray, everything works fine, but if it's in tray, program finishes. What's way to solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the `self` argument from the layout constructor. The widget argument of a layout is used to automatically set that layout on the widget, but since you're going to set the layout on another widget (and no layout could be set on a QMainWindow), that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the show function when calling the dialog window.

```py
def dial_func(self):
    self.show()
    text, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
        self, 'Input dialog', 'Enter your name')

    if ok:
        print('simple text', text)
```

This solution will solve your issue.

Comment: and then self.hide() after ok, but if I don't have any other useful information in main window? Summary I will use main window only for working Qdialog... that's a bit strange.